# How do I use the keycloak access token in angular

Tags: angular, keycloak

I've integrated the keycloak adapter in my spring boot application, as described in the documentation. The workflow is working.
Initially, I was using the session token-store in the properties, but I want to get rid of that and be stateless. So, I changed the option to a cookie token-store.

I can see that my Spring Boot app does send the keycloak access token in the KEYCLOAK_ADAPTER_STATE cookie ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2Y0.jpg)). As expected, it's flagged as an HTTP cookie.

However, further angular http requests do not send that cookie when I query my back-end, even if I turn on the withCredentials option in the query.

```
let options : RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
options.withCredentials = true;
this.http.get('myservice', options)
```

How can I use that token in stateless http calls ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the [angular-keycloak documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular) HttpClient interceptor by default will add the Authorization header in the format of: Authorization: Bearer `TOKEN` for all the HTTP requests from your application to the server.

You can configure request URLs that you want to exclude from adding the HTTP Authorization header with the keycloak token in the HTTPClient interceptor configuration.

The HttpClient interceptor can be configured in the keycloak initializer function in the app-init.ts (refer the angular-keycloak documentation) as below;

```
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

export function initializer(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<any> {
    return (): Promise<any> => keycloak.init({
        config: {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
            realm: 'your-realm',
            clientId: 'client-id'
        },
        initOptions: {
            onLoad: 'login-required',
            checkLoginIframe: false
        },
        enableBearerInterceptor: true,
        bearerPrefix: 'Bearer',
        bearerExcludedUrls: [
            '/assets',
            '/clients/public']
    });
}
```

Comment: What if we dont want to use angular-keycloak npm package?

Comment: @withoutOne well, use raw keycloak.js provided by keycloak to implement the functionalities needed.

Comment: @devansvd yes, I tried and I didnt like it :) keycloak-angular is good as last version

Answer (score 1):

Use [Interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses):

> HTTP Interception is a major feature of @angular/common/http. With
>   interception, you declare interceptors that inspect and transform HTTP
>   requests from your application to the server. The same interceptors
>   may also inspect and transform the server's responses on their way
>   back to the application. Multiple interceptors form a
>   forward-and-backward chain of request/response handlers
>
> import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
>
> ```
> @Injectable()
> export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
>
>   constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}
>
>   intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
>     // Get the auth token from the service.
>     const authToken = this.auth.getAuthorizationToken();
>
>     // Clone the request and replace the original headers with
>     // cloned headers, updated with the authorization.
>     const authReq = req.clone({
>       headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authToken)
>     });
>
>     // send cloned request with header to the next handler.
>     return next.handle(authReq);
>   }
> }
> ```

...

> I think you should set `options.withCredentials = true;` to any requests

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });

    return next
      .handle(req)
      .do(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {}
      }, (error: any) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (error.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but I do not have any token to add, as I do not have access to it (it's an HTTP-only cookie). I would have expected that the browser sends it automatically (as the JSESSIONID is).

Comment: @ThomasGilbert, I think you should set `options.withCredentials = true;` to any requests

Comment: Already tried this with the RequestOptions parameter (see my post's code sample) of the standard HTTP service :(.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The initial request URL to get to my page was "/app/mymodule" so the keycloak HTTP token was bound to the /app path; but the JS http request I do to query my back-end is "/services/myservice", so the browser does not send the cookie as the root path does not match. I'm moved my services under /app/services instead and now the token is sent as expected, and properly verified :).

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular.

It makes the process a lot easier with great documentation.

It uses interceptors that it has built into the npm package so you dont need to worry about attaching the token to each request.